# Match non-word characters until enclosing non-word characters if found

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match any non-word character from the beginning and end position of a string, but *if* it comes across a non-word character which encloses a string, I want it to stop matching right before it.

I created the following regex pattern:

```
^\W+(?!(\W+)((?!\1).)+\1)?
```

I expected it to match like is shown in the following image since it would match any non-word characters from the beginning of the string until it reached the enclosing quotes from the pattern in the negative lookahead:

[image: !@#$%""<>test (string")-+/;,]

But the result was this:

[image: !@#$%""<>test (string")-+/;,]

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdKyLA/1)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```php
^\W*?(\W)(?=.*?\b\1\W*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jn9mNT/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\W*?` - zero or more non-word chars, as few as possible
- `(\W)` - a non-word char captured into Group 1
- `(?=.*?\b\1\W*$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `\1` - same value as in Group 1
  - `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be it. However, if there are no enclosing characters found it should just match all the non-word characters from the beginning until the pattern is broken. If I remove the quotes in the demo so that nothing is enclosed, the pattern doesn't match anything. It should then match `!@#$%""<>`.

Comment: @KidDiamond Then you can also match if after a word char there can be any chars but the last non-word captured into Group 1: `^\W*?(\W)(?=.*?\b\1\W*$|\w(?:(?!\1).)*$)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jn9mNT/2).

Comment: I have read this question a few times, how did you come up with an answer that fast? :-) Brilliant solution ++

Comment: @Thefourthbird It is a question that has already been asked and then deleted, but it was asked in a very unclear way, so this time, I could get the gist quicker. Also, a bit of intuition helped.